Unity PhysicsRaycaster not recognizing correct edges of 3D collider with OnMouseEnter
I'm using the PhysicsRaycaster on the MainCamera, trying to detect hover. It seems like it should be very simple but the collider never lines up, it's like it's smaller the to the x+ y- of where it should be.
gif: doesn't hover where i expect
`
using UnityEngine;
public class TextOverlay : MonoBehaviour
{
public Texture2D[] cursorTexture;
public Renderer rend;

private void Start()
{

    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    ChangeCursor(false);
}

public void OnMouseEnter()
{
    rend.material.color = Color.red;
    ChangeCursor(true);
}

public void OnMouseOver()
{
    rend.material.color -= new Color(0.1F, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
}


public void OnMouseExit()
{
    rend.material.color = Color.white;
    ChangeCursor(false);
}


public void ChangeCursor(bool value)
{
    Debug.Log("change cursor: " + value);
    if (value)
        Cursor.SetCursor(cursorTexture[1], Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
    else
        Cursor.SetCursor(cursorTexture[0], Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);

}

}

`
I expect the cursor to change and the sub to highlight red when the cursor passes over the edge of the collider.
I've checked the 3D box collider fits the cube, the Physics Raycaster is attached to the main camera, there are no other cameras, tried three versions of unity, new project, with and without Cinemachine brain. (Will eventually need to work with Cinemachine.) I've tried OnMouseEnter/Exit, OnPointerEnter/Exit, and the EventTrigger.

PhysicsRaycaster has nothing to do with OnMouseXXX events, just make sure your collider meets the requirements: https://docs.unity3d.com/6000.0/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html

Are you sure the collider matches the visuals? Maybe there is a scaling difference

If anyone has this issue, it's with the Cursor code. "Vector2.zero" is not the center of the image, I needed to use  new Vector2(_cursorTexture.width / 2, _cursorTexture.height / 2);
